# If statement in for loop only running once in JAVA

Tags: java, eclipse, if-statement

Im trying to make an if statement that deducts 2 points for each time the verb 'me' or 'I' is found in a string. To do this I have split the string into separate words. To test I changed the string to have 2x "me". But the score is only deducted once instead of twice (as there are 2 x "me"). Tried adding a while loop but it just kept deducting until negative. Baby language please, I am a beginner coder. Thanks in advance

```
public static void main(String[] args) { //getWordLength() { // Checking word length. Less than 6 means reviewer can't weigh out positives and negatives
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         int ReviewScore = 30;
        
         String Review = "me I me, from Montreal";
         String[] words = Review.split("\\s+");
         
          System.out.println("Word Count is: "+words.length);
           int wordlength = Integer.valueOf(words.length);
          
           
            if (wordlength< 6) { 
                 ReviewScore -=4; // deducts 4pts if review less than 6 words
                System.out.println("Score is "+ ReviewScore);
                
            }
            verbCount( ReviewScore,Review);
            
    }
    
        public static  void verbCount (int ReviewScore, String Review) { //Count verbs 'I' or 'me'
    
        for (String s : Review.split("\n") ) { // splits review into separate words
            
        
            if (s.contains("me" )){ // Checks for 'me' or 'I'
            
                
                ReviewScore -= 2;
                System.out.println("Score is "+ ReviewScore); // deducts by 2 pts 
                
                
                if ( s.contains ("I")) {
                    ReviewScore -= 2;
                    System.out.println("Score is "+ ReviewScore);
                
                }

        }
    
    
}
```

}
}

Comment: Do you want to output the score really that often? Each time you decrease it, you also output it.

Comment: Debug you code. Hint: Review.split("\n") vs  Review.split("\\s+").

Comment: I'll probably remove it at some point but it helps me see that the code is working as expected

Comment: Once you split on word boundaries you probably want to use `s.equals("me")` instead of contains unless yo want to deduct "me" points for words such as "mesmerised".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you should return the review score from your method `verbcount`.

Second you split the text twice, once by word boundaries ("\s+"), but inside your method `verbcount` you split it by newlines ("\n") and therefore the method is not working as intended.

Instead of the string to review, pass the `words` array into that method and don't split it again!

Third your ifs are nested, so the `s.contains ("I")` will only be checked, if also `s.contains("me")` - this can happen because you split by lines, but only once per line. Also once you split words, you will never get into that second if-branch.
Pull it up one level to be in parallel to the first `if` inside the method.